# Why does my simple OpenGL shadow map fail?

Tags: opengl, shadow-mapping, jogl

I want to render a simple shadow map for grass, where closer looks brighter and further looks darker, from the view of the light point. I can't get it to work.

Here is the relevant code:

```
//setting up buffers
gl.glGenFramebuffers(1, framebuff);
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuff.get(0));

gl.glGenTextures(2, textureBuff);
gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBuff.get(0));
gl.glTexStorage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL4.GL_R32F, displayWidth, displayHeight);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.glFramebufferTexture(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL4.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, textureBuff.get(0), 0);

gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureBuff.get(1));
gl.glTexStorage2D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL4.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, displayWidth, displayHeight);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL4.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_MODE, GL4.GL_COMPARE_REF_TO_TEXTURE);
gl.glTexParameteri(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL4.GL_TEXTURE_COMPARE_FUNC, GL4.GL_LEQUAL);
gl.glFramebufferTexture(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL4.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, textureBuff.get(1), 0);
gl.glDrawBuffer(GL4.GL_NONE);

if(gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
         System.out.println(gl.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER));
```

Drawing command (unsure if it's correct):

```
//gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuff.get(0));
gl.glViewport(0, 0, displayWidth, displayWidth);
gl.glEnable(GL4.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
gl.glPolygonOffset(2.0f, 4.0f);

/*
gl.glClearBufferfv(GL4.GL_COLOR, 0, new float[] {0, 0, 0}, 0);
gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);
gl.glClear(GL4.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);*/

setupMVPMatrix();
gl.glBindVertexArray(vaoBuff.get(0));

gl.glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
gl.glDrawArraysInstanced(GL4.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 5, 512 * 512);

gl.glDisable(GL4.GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL);
//gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

When I comment the `glBindFramebuffer()`, the grass appears correctly with the white color (from the light point of view, which shows the matrix should be correct):

[image: drawing without shadow map]

But if I call `glBindFramebuffer()` with the depth test enabled, everything just disappears. I have also checked the framebuffer status, yet it seems there is no error.

What might cause this?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, I didn't understand the meaning of off-screen rendering at the beginning. Just render the depth value stored in the texture into the default framebuffer for display, and everything work just fine. I can't believe I spent 5 days on this.

[image: shadow of grass]

```
gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuff.get(0));
draw scene...(storing the depth value into the depth texture)

gl.glBindFramebuffer(GL4.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
draw scene...(comparing with the depth texture stored)
```